# Compiling NCURSES src on HPUX

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, hp-ux

I am trying to compile ncurses-5.7 from source and after running ./configure I get the following error:

```
configure: error: Your compiler does not appear to recognize prototypes.
You have the following choices:
        a. adjust your compiler options
        b. get an up-to-date compiler
        c. use a wrapper such as unproto
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: What about following the suggestions given out by configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting the following line in configure file worked.

```
export CC="cc"
```

Got the answer from [Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/xml@gnome.org/msg05157.html).

Comment: If that was your problem, you should have run ./configure CC=gcc

Comment: I did but the configure is setting the variable again based on if [ "`uname -s`" = "HP-UX" ] condition, therefore I have commented out that line so it cannot reset the variable again.

Answer (score 0):

As configure output suggests, you should either install an HPUX version of gcc or use unproto as a wrapper

Comment: gcc was installed on the system. export CC=gcc doesn't work, so I checked the configure and there is following line which cause this issue. <code>export CC="cc"</code>. so after commenting that line the configure script run successfully.